# WPF - How to centre title text on a control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, outlook

I'm using the XAML designer and C# within Visual Studio 2017 to create controls for an Outlook Addin. I'm currently working on an about screen for the addin.

I'm attempting to remove the icon and move the text to the centre of the header.

[image]

The example below is from Outlook's about screen, this has the header I wish to achieve.

[image]

This is my first time using XAML so I wanted to know if there's a property that needs to be changed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid there is no property or simple way or doing this. You will probably have to create your own custom window from scratch to be able to center the title of the title bar. There is an example of how you could do this here: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/.

You could also take a look at the `WindowChrome` class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome(v=vs.110).aspx.

To simply hide the minimize and maximize buttons, you could use some P/Invoke: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/11/30/disabling-or-hiding-the-minimize-maximize-or-close-button-of-a-wpf-window/

Comment: I suppose it'll be a good learning exercise for me, thank you for the suggestions I will be attempting to create a custom window and I'll put the controls upon the custom windows instead!